# Weird prototyping error: Cpp's and Headers

Tags: c++, class, object, prototype, declaration

This is the following error I'm receiving

**error: forward declaration of 'class A'|**

I'm trying to prototype the classes and make them globally available.
I figured it would be best to explain this via an image so here it is:

**Oops also forgot to mention that FileA.cpp also #includes External.h**

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. And who codes with a non-monospace font!?

Answer (score 2):

For instantiating objects (automatic or with `new`), one needs to have a complete definition of the type visible. The `class A` body should be visible to Main.cpp.

Incomplete types which are just forward declared, have limited usage. It can be used as:

1. pointer
2. reference
3. a template parameter

e.g.

```
class A;
class X {
  A* p;
  A& r;
  std::vector<A> v;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

main is trying to construct A when it knows nothing about the class, other than that it exists. You need the definition available to Main.cpp, not hidden in another cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an object (with `new`) without a complete class defintion.

Either move the defintion into `External.h` or use a factory method to return a valid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the class `A` you need the *full* definition of it. How else will the compiler know what methods and variables it has? And that includes the construction of instances of the object, even when just creating pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A forward declaration of a class is enough to declare a pointer or a reference to that class, but nothing else. If you want to use class' functions (and that includes constructors), you need to have the complete definition avaliable at the point of usage.